# Auto Echo text in php with sessions

Tags: php, session

I am using the session to show some text. The result I want is **After `10s` of logging it should echo `some text`**.

I tried:-

**Functions.php**

```
function LoginSessionExpired() {

    if(!isset($_SESSION['first_visit']))
    {
    $_SESSION['first_visit']=time();
    }else{
        $login_session_durations = 10;
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin_time']) and isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){  
            if(((time() - $_SESSION['first_visit']) > $login_session_durations)){ 
                return true; 
            } 
        }
    }
    }
```

**Dashboard.php**

```
session_start();
include("functions.php");
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    if(LoginSessionExpired()) {
    echo "Ok";
}
}
```

But it  `echoes` only when the page is refreshed, I want the auto show without refreshing.

Comment: You'll need client side programming for this

Comment: Maybe you could echo a `<script>` tag with a `setTimeout`?

Comment: @Akintunde from where should I get client side programming?

Comment: @Manav Can you explain by editing the code and post in answer.

Comment: Do you want us to code if for you?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone May or you may provide Idea